# Can I use double quotes in an attribute value of angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, quotes, double-quotes

Can you suggest how to assign `{{$count}} times per month <span ng-include="'views/partials/month-dates.html'"></span>` to `translate-plural` attribute?

E.g. the following expression causes a parsing error:

```
<translate translate-n="notification.Data[flightType][direction].Days.length" translate-plural="{{$count}} times per month <span ng-include=\"'views/partials/month-dates.html'\"></span>">
    N times per month on <span ng-include="'views/partials/month-dates.html'"></span>
</translate>
```

Comment: try `translate-plural="{{$count}} times per month <span ng-include=\"views/partials/month-dates.html\""`

Comment: I've fixed my problem replacing the constant by a variables inside the ng-include directive:

 <div ng-init="monthDatesView = 'views/partials/month-dates.html'"></div>
 <translate translate-n="notification.Data[flightType][direction].Days.length" translate-plural="{{$count}} times per month on <span ng-include='monthDatesView'></span>">
     N times per month on <span ng-include="monthDatesView"></span>
 </translate>

Comment: However the question is still open: is it possible to use double quotes inside angular directives?

Comment: @Tamil Selvan your solution not only causes the parsing error but also has a syntaxt error: you do not escape the constant with a quote in the beginning.

Comment: try `translate-plural="{{$count}} times per month <span ng-include=\"'views/partials/month-dates.html'\""`

Comment: That's exactly what I posted. This solution causes a parsing error. I wrote it in the post.

Comment: can you make fiddle or something ?

Comment: You can create a snippet that shows how to use double quotes in Angular directive. I showed how the issue can be avoided in the second comment. But the question is still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I've not received any good answer, I'll share what I found on this topic.

- It seems that there is no way to escape double quotes in Angular
  views.
- If you do need to use double quotes inside directive attribute
  there are 2 ways:

  1. If it is possible (in my case it wasn't) use single quotes to wrap
     the attribute value and double quotes in the attribute value or vice
     versa
  2. You can also replace a constant with double quotes in the
     attribute value with a variable like I did

see the solution below

```
<div ng-init="monthDatesView = 'views/partials/month-dates.html'"></div>
<translate translate-n="notification.Data[flightType][direction].Days.length" translate-plural="{{$count}} times per month on <span ng-include='monthDatesView'></span>">
    N times per month on <span ng-include="monthDatesView"></span>
</translate>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using `&quot;` or `&#34;`? I just had a similar issue with an angular expression inside an attribute and it worked like this.